# Change the text color of my input field when using the standard datepicker in Edge and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background of my date field on my form when I make a selection from the standard datepicker in Edge and Chrome.

my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(":input").change(function () {
        toggleEmptyInputs($(this));
   });
});
```

my date field is:

```
<input type="date" name="Birthday" class="date mandatory empty validationerror" id="i105">
```

The ID is automatically made and can change for different forms. So I need to use the name or.....

What I really want is when I use the `datepicker` that the empty part in the class is removed (basically that is what the `toggleEmptyInputs` function does in my jquery).

I tried to use :

```
$(":input").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        toggleEmptyInputs($(this));
    }
});
```

but this does not work and also produce an error in firefox as `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker` is not a function.

Thanks in advance for your help

the toggle function is

```
function toggleEmptyInputs(inputElement) {
    if (inputElement.val()) {
        inputElement.removeClass("empty");
        inputElement.closest(".col").removeClass("hidelabel");
    } else {
        inputElement.addClass("empty");
        inputElement.closest(".col").addClass("hidelabel");
    }
}
```

and works fine for all other fields.

the fiddle works fine because of the `.empty:after {content: "empty"}` in the css
SO I am going to incorporate this in my removeClass function

Thanks Scimonster

Comment: If `$(...).datepicker is not a function.` you probably didn't include jQuery UI. Which you might not even need.

Comment: I just tried  the .datepicker  as I do not know what else to use

Comment: The datepicker responds to the `change` event, at least in my Chrome. Maybe it's some other part of the code causing an issue. Can you include your `toggleEmptyInputs` function?

Comment: just added the toggle function. The jquery onchange is not executing at all

Comment: Seems to be working for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qzn5aa1k/).

Comment: You are right that it works in this fiddle. Unfortunately I cannot put a breakpoint in the fiddle to see or can I (I haven't used fiddle before). On my form, when I put a breakpoint in the ready function I never come to this point.

Comment: I recommend you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem you're coming across, because there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code you've posted so far.

Comment: if you remove the css then it doesnot work so there is a solution which I did not post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

to

```
 $(window).load(function ()
```

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate: "I want to change the background of my date field on my form when I make a selection" you can simply add a class.

Example: with `colorme` class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='date']").change(function() {
    console.log('got here');
    toggleEmptyInputs($(this));
  });
});

function toggleEmptyInputs(inputElement) {
  var hasValue = !!inputElement.val();
  inputElement.toggleClass("empty", !hasValue).toggleClass('colorme', hasValue);
  inputElement.closest(".col").toggleClass("hidelabel", hasValue);
}
```

CSS:

```
input.colorme {
  color: lime;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I click on the datepicker to select a date the onchange is not fired